# Using stack overflow to generate a knowledge base for openQA

Tags: discussion

There is this tool called [openQA](http://open.qa/) which is open source and is used by SUSE, [openSUSE](http://openqa.opensuse.org/), [Fedora](http://openqa.fedoraproject.org/) and to some extent by [Debian](http://openqa.debian.net/) to test distributions as an automated testing tool, you can think of it as Selenium but for operating systems.

While we have some [documentation,](http://open.qa/docs/) we struggle a bit to spread the knowledge among users, and would like to know if stack overflow is really a good place to start building a knowledge base under a tag like [selenium-webdriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) for example does.

(this is a repost as requested to be handled in META)

Answer (score 2):

I see no problems with this, provided that the tool creators and developers disclose their affiliations when they post, and that the questions asked are valid questions - that is, they are the kinds of questions a user of the tool would ask.

It's not uncommon for small software development companies and open source projects to direct help questions to the appropriate Stack Exchange network sites, so as long as the openQA people stay within the SE [Code of Conduct](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/conduct), they are welcome to build a body of knowledge here for testers who need to test distributions.

Comment: Do they need to disclose in every post? I personally would only request they disclose if they're recommending it. If someone is already using the product, it seems fine to me to scoot by undisclosed. My $0.02.

Comment: I'd prefer disclosures in recommendations and posts that are functionally link only answers (I've seen way too many of those come through the review queues, alas). Other posts I'm less likely to have issues since it makes sense for a prod owner to answer a question about their product - although then the disclosure can also act to make the answer more authoritative.

Comment: Good point. Any time you're generating links to your site, it's a good idea. It certainly can't hurt!